# Getting the emberjs starter-kit to work with coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

i'm trying to get the starter-kit example of ember.js to work directly with an app written in coffeescript (with the use of http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js).
I want to use this in an development environment, without the need to convert the coffescript to javascript first (manually or with tools like jitter).

Basically i just replaced the line

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

with the lines

```
<script src="js/libs/coffee-script-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="coffee/app.coffee"></script>
```

in the index.html

All changes i've made can be found in my fork on github at https://github.com/GordonSchmidt/starter-kit

The coffescript itself seems to be fine, because when i convert it to javascript first the starter-kit application works with this javascript. But when i use the coffeescript directly it throws the error "assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'App.MyView'" in line 45 of ember-0.9.8.1.js. The coffee-script.js all by itself seems to work as well (see demo.html). So it has to be a conflict between ember.js and coffee-script.js.

But I'm not able to find this error. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from coffeescript.org

> The usual caveats about CoffeeScript apply — your inline scripts will
>   run within a closure wrapper, so if you want to expose global
>   variables or functions, attach them to the window object.

your coffeescript should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
    window.App = App = Em.Application.create()

    App.MyView = Em.View.extend(
      mouseDown: -> window.alert "hello world!"
    )​
</script>
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/253/) for a fiddle

Comment: Your fiddle is working, but it still doesn't work in my standalone version. I don't see how the coffeescript is converted to javascript on jsfiddle, so i'm not able to reproduce this outside of jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you tried putting the coffeescript in the tag instead of in a separate file? Because I don't think coffeescript is able to load external recources.

Comment: Ah, that really is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Well, i may have been to fast with my last comment. The external *.coffee script is executed (at least if no emberjs is presend). See the demo.html in my github repo.

Comment: Handlebars may be in the way for the external loading of coffee scripts.

Comment: Your app.coffee doesn't contain window.App = App on gh. see [pull-req](https://github.com/GordonSchmidt/starter-kit/pull/1)

Comment: The window.App = App is only a little part of the solution. The problem seems to be, that the compilation of the coffeescript may be
executed at the wrong time. So the scripts may not run in the same order as they are defined. See coffeescript issue for details:
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1054 In my last commit i added require.js to handle script loading and a coffeescript plugin for require.js to solve the problem.